# How to split my table into 2 pages?

Tags: tables, longtable, tabularx

I can't find out how to split my table into 2 pages! I tried `longtable` package, but nothing worked.

My table contains many rows.

```
    \documentclass[12pt]{report}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 

    \usepackage{booktabs}
    \usepackage{tabularx}
    \usepackage{adjustbox}
    \usepackage{multirow}
    \begin{document}

    \begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|l|X|X|X|}
     \hline % horizontal line and | for vertical line %
     \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{characteristics}}         & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{sub-characteristics}}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{metrics}} &\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{citation}}
         \tabularnewline\hline \hline 

    \multirow{ 6}{*}{Effectiveness(hight)} & 
        -Minimal memory load(low) &&  QUIM model 
        &\ &
         -Minimal memory load(low) && QUIM model
         &\ &
         -Minimal memory load(low) &&
         &\ &
         -Minimal memory load(low) &&
         &\ &
         -Minimal memory load(low) &&
         &\ &
        -Minimal memory load(low) &&
         &\ &
         -Minimal memory load(low) &&QUIM&
        \tabularnewline\hline

    \multirow{ 7}{*}{Satisfaction}& -Attractiveness & &QUIM model
        &\ & 
        -Attractiveness & &QUIM model 
        & \ &
        -Attractiveness & &
        & \ &
        -Attractiveness & &
        & \ &
        -Attractiveness & &
        & \ &
        -Attractiveness & &
        & \ &
        -Attractiveness & & &

        \tabularnewline\hline


       \multirow{ 8}{*}{ efficiency(hight)}& -Minimal memory load(low) & &  QUIM model
        & \ &
        -Minimal memory load(low) & &QUIM 
        & \ &
        -Minimal memory load(low) & &QUIM
        &\ &
       -Minimal memory load(low) & &QUIM
        & \ &
        -Minimal memory load(low) & &QUIM
        & \ &
        -Minimal memory load(low) & & QUIM
        & \ & 
        -Minimal memory load(low) & & QUIM
        & \ &
        -Minimal memory load(low) & &QUIM &
        \tabularnewline\hline

       \multirow{ 2}{*}{User error protection} & & & &
        \tabularnewline\hline 

       \multirow{ 11}{*}{ Usefulness} &&&
       &\ &
       -Flexibility && 
       &\ &
        -Flexibility && 
       &\ &
        -Flexibility &&
       &\ &
        -Flexibility &&
       &\ &
        -Flexibility &&
       &\ &
       -Flexibility &&
       &\ &
        -Flexibility &&
       &\ &
        -Flexibility &&
       &\ &
        -Flexibility &&
       &\ &
        -Flexibility && QUIM & 
            \tabularnewline\hline

        \multirow{ 7}{*}{Satisfaction}& -Attractiveness & &QUIM model
        &\ & 
        -Attractiveness & &QUIM model 
        & \ &
        -Attractiveness & &
        & \ &
        -Attractiveness & &
        & \ &
        -Attractiveness & &
        & \ &
        -Attractiveness & &
        & \ &
        -Attractiveness & & &

        \tabularnewline\hline
        \multirow{ 7}{*}{Satisfaction}& -Attractiveness & &QUIM model
        &\ & 
        -Attractiveness & &QUIM model 
        & \ &
        -Attractiveness & &
        & \ &
        -Attractiveness & &
        & \ &
        -Attractiveness & &
        & \ &
        -Attractiveness & &
        & \ &
        -Attractiveness & & &

        \tabularnewline\hline
        \multirow{ 7}{*}{Satisfaction}& -Attractiveness & &QUIM model
        &\ & 
        -Attractiveness & &QUIM model 
        & \ &
        -Attractiveness & &
        & \ &
        -Attractiveness & &
        & \ &
        -Attractiveness & &
        & \ &
        -Attractiveness & &
        & \ &
        -Attractiveness & & &

        \tabularnewline\hline

\multirow{ 7}{*}{Satisfaction}& -Attractiveness & &QUIM model
        &\ & 
        -Attractiveness & &QUIM model 
        & \ &
        -Attractiveness & &
        & \ &
        -Attractiveness & &
        & \ &
        -Attractiveness & &
        & \ &
        -Attractiveness & &
        & \ &
        -Attractiveness & & &

        \tabularnewline\hline

\multirow{ 7}{*}{Satisfaction}& -Attractiveness & &QUIM model
        &\ & 
        -Attractiveness & &QUIM model 
        & \ &
        -Attractiveness & &
        & \ &
        -Attractiveness & &
        & \ &
        -Attractiveness & &
        & \ &
        -Attractiveness & &
        & \ &
        -Attractiveness & & &

        \tabularnewline\hline


     \end{tabularx} 
      \caption{A list of usability criteria }
    \label{table:usability criteria}   
    \end{table} 
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Instead `\begin{table} ... \end{table}` use `begin{longtable}{<columns type} ...\end{longtable}`, remove `tabularx`, replace `X` column type with `p{...}` and consolidate number of columns. For this you need to add `\usepackage{longtable}` in document preamble.

Comment: What are all those `& \ &`? The number of `&`does not correspond to the declared number of columns.

Comment: Please add a screenshot or a sketch to your question, showing how the layout of the resulting table should be ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a highly imperfect attempt to convert your code to something that can fit into a `longtable` environment. I say "highly imperfect" because I had to make a lot of design decisions, such as (a) what to make of all the instances of "`& \ &`" and (b) assigning equal widths to the four columns. I've also gotten rid of all `\multirow` wrappers.

The following screenshot shows just the first few rows of the `longtable`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry} % set page parameters appropriately

\usepackage{booktabs,longtable,array,ragged2e}
\newlength\mylen
\setlength{\mylen}{\dimexpr0.25\textwidth-1.5\tabcolsep}
\newcolumntype{P}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}p{\mylen}}
\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{@{} *{4}{P} @{}}
\caption{A list of usability criteria } \label{tab:criteria}
\label{table:usability criteria}\\
\toprule 
\textbf{Characteristics} & 
\textbf{Subcharacter\-istics}&
\textbf{Metrics} &
\textbf{Citation} \\
\midrule
\endfirsthead

\multicolumn{4}{c}{Table \ref{tab:criteria}, cont'd}\\
\addlinespace
\toprule 
\textbf{Characteristics} & 
\textbf{Subcharacter\-istics}&
\textbf{Metrics} &
\textbf{Citation} \\
\midrule
\endhead

\midrule
\endfoot
\bottomrule
\endlastfoot


     Effectiveness (height) & 
     -Minimal memory load (low) &&  QUIM model 
     \\
     &-Minimal memory load (low) && QUIM model
     \\
     &-Minimal memory load (low) &
     \\
     &-Minimal memory load (low) &
     \\
     &-Minimal memory load (low) &
     \\
     &-Minimal memory load (low) &
     \\
     &-Minimal memory load (low) &&QUIM
     \\
     \midrule

    Satisfaction & -Attractiveness & &QUIM model
    \\ 
    &-Attractiveness & &QUIM model 
    \\
    &-Attractiveness & &
    \\
    &-Attractiveness & &
    \\
    &-Attractiveness & &
    \\
    &-Attractiveness & &
    \\
    &-Attractiveness & & 

    \\
    \midrule

    Efficiency (height) 
    & -Minimal memory load (low) & &  QUIM model
    \\
    &-Minimal memory load (low) & &QUIM 
    \\
    &-Minimal memory load (low) & &QUIM
    \\
    &-Minimal memory load (low) & &QUIM
    \\
    &-Minimal memory load (low) & &QUIM
    \\
    &-Minimal memory load (low) & & QUIM
    \\ 
    &-Minimal memory load (low) & & QUIM
    \\
    &-Minimal memory load (low) & &QUIM 
    \\
    \midrule

    User error protection 
    \\
    \midrule 

    Usefulness
    &-Flexibility && 
    \\
    &-Flexibility && 
    \\
    &-Flexibility &&
    \\
    &-Flexibility &&
    \\
    &-Flexibility &&
    \\
    &-Flexibility &&
    \\
    &-Flexibility &&
    \\
    &-Flexibility &&
    \\
    &-Flexibility &&
    \\
    &-Flexibility && QUIM 
    \\
    \midrule

    Satisfaction& -Attractiveness & &QUIM model
    \\ 
    &-Attractiveness & &QUIM model 
    \\
    &-Attractiveness & &
    \\
    &-Attractiveness & &
    \\
    &-Attractiveness & &
    \\
    &-Attractiveness & &
    \\
    &-Attractiveness & &
    \\
    \midrule

    Satisfaction& -Attractiveness & &QUIM model
    \\ 
    &-Attractiveness & &QUIM model 
    \\
    &-Attractiveness & &
    \\
    &-Attractiveness & &
    \\
    &-Attractiveness & &
    \\
    &-Attractiveness & &
    \\
    &-Attractiveness & &
    \\
    \midrule

    Satisfaction& -Attractiveness &&QUIM model
    \\ 
    &-Attractiveness & &QUIM model 
    \\
    &-Attractiveness & &
    \\
    &-Attractiveness & &
    \\
    &-Attractiveness & &
    \\
    &-Attractiveness & &
    \\
    &-Attractiveness & & 
    \\
    \midrule

    Satisfaction& -Attractiveness & &QUIM model
    \\ 
    &-Attractiveness & &QUIM model 
    \\
    &-Attractiveness & &
    \\
    &-Attractiveness & &
    \\
    &-Attractiveness & &
    \\
    &-Attractiveness & &
    \\
    &-Attractiveness & & 
    \\

\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Appreciate your efforts @Mico ! , is just what i need .